# Not able to start OpenStack glance-api

Tags: openstack, openstack-glance

Within the process of installing OpenStack on my servers, I'm at the point to configure and verify the glance service. Everything seems to work, but I'm not able to create an image, caused by an non starting glance-api.

The dedicated `glance-api.log` doesn't provide any applicable information, so what can I do to solve this problem?

Database sync worked, config done like suggested in the docs[1](https://docs.openstack.org/glance/victoria/install/install-ubuntu.html)

Did anyone suffer the same problem like I do?

Comment: What happens when you attempt to start Glance? What is the service's status (`systemctl status glance-api`)? Have you checked the journal (`sudo journalctl -u glance-api`)? If you don't find anything useful, try running glance-api from the command line. Use the service definition (`systemctl cat glance-api`) for inspiration. I think there is a debug option, too.

Comment: Thank for the many information! I solved the problem starting `glance-api` directly from cmd. Problem was an incorrect config. Misspelled `auth_url`, was `auth_uri` in my case. Changed that, now it works perfectly!